Why does cv2.calcHist() have different minimum and maximum values than the array from which it is generating a histogram?
Overview:

I want to visualize the pixel value distribution of an image that has had it's pixel values normalized (range bounds [0, 1]) and use cv2.calcHist() to obtain the histogram.

Code:
def create_histogram(array: np.ndarray):
    array_min, array_max = np.min(array), np.max(array)
    print(f"Array: min {array_min} . . .  max {array_max}")
    hist = cv2.calcHist([array], channels = [0], mask = None, histSize = [100], ranges = [0, 1])
    histo_min, histo_max = np.min(hist), np.max(hist)
    print(f"Histogram: min {histo_min} . . .  max {histo_max}")
    return hist

Output:
Array: min 0.0 . . .  max 1.0 Histogram: min 0.0 . . .  max 4152712.0
Comprehension Check:
From my understanding, the original array is correct being passed to the function and read as it should be, with minimum and maximum pixel values of 1.
(1) What I do not understand, if why does the histogram have a maximum value that does not correspond with the image maximum value?
(2) If I have set the range to be [0, 1] bound in the cv2.calcHist() function, why does my histogram output an x-axis that indicates a range of beyond 4?
(3) Finally, I do not understand where this '1e7' is coming from in the histogram when it is plotted [Fig. 1]
Fig. 1 - Picture of Histogram Output
If it is of relevance, this is the line of code that is used to generate the histogram:
plt.hist(histo_dict[k], bins = 100, color = 'deeppink', edgecolor = 'black', alpha = 0.2)

I tried to create a histogram using cv2.calcHist(), however this is not producing expected results.
edit: I believe that the maximum value from the histogram array is actually just the length of the highest volume bin. This still does not explain the x-axis range appearing to stretch beyond the [0, 1] upper-bound limit, appearing on the final histogram.

Well, if I have 100 bins, I would expect that the x-axis should be ranging from 0-1 then.
I still don't understand how the x-axis is showing 1,2,3,4 as the grid plot background, however. Or what the 1e7 indicates.

One thing that I have discovered, is that calcHist() is recording the total number of pixels that belong to each bin. So what you said previously is making more sense to me. Now my problem is figuring out how to have the bins correspond with 0 to 100, with a 0.01 interval - this is what I would like on the x-axis, as opposed to seeing the delineiations of the bins, i.e the 0... 1e7 range. But I know a little bit more about how everything is working, thank you for all of your help so far!

Hi! Everything has been cleared up now. Thank you for all of your effort, it helped me in understanding things a lot, even if the problem in the end was my own bone-headed brain!

I have been trying to plot a histogram of a histogram. This is wrong.
img = cv2.imread('mountain.jpg')

array = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

plt.hist(array)

If you want to plot the cv2 result (an ndarray), use plt.plot()
img = cv2.imread('mountain.jpg')

array = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

plt.plot(array)


or you can use numpy.ravel()  to reshape the image to 1D array as plt.hist() requires. try plt.hist(numpy.ravel(array),bins=100,range=[0,100])
